# Feels like I am being lied to about the possibility of a raise

Tags: salary, manager, promotion, raise, salary-review

I have been working a tech company as a developer for the past few years and 8 months ago I asked for a raise in salary.

I spoke with my engineering manager, and his response was: "Lets finish your two current projects and then we can reevaluate you current salary." Those two current projects had a timeframe of completion in 6 months.

I agreed and proceeded to complete the current projects, then nothing.  A bit later, I asked my manager again. This time was a bit more positive.

I explained that I have not received a raise since I started working here two and a half years ago. His reply was that my first six months of employment cannot be counted, since it's a probationary period and that it's only been two years, not two and half.

I was then told in June that the following month we would discuss a promotion, along with a raise in salary.

July came and went and there has still been no raise, promotion, or discussion of either.

Looking at the current market medians of my position, along with other companies, I see that I am significantly underpaid compared to my coworkers.

My company is also paying others at my position 30% more in salary then I am paid, including the starting base I have seen on the postings.

I'm annoyed by the fact that I am being underpaid, and feel that I am being led on about raises and promotions.

What are some options I should move forward with?

- Should I talk to the director of the team, going over my manager to get answers ?
- Should I just forget it and just look for a new job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @kate No, since I have not received a raise at all, and although similar the situation differ greatly in key points. I already approached my boss twice, I never received a raise one, I am starting to think I am lowest paid in my current position.

Comment: it might help if you edited your question to make those key points clear.

Comment: I think they are pretty clear. Don't really understand where you feel there are gaps.

Comment: While you may not have a raise at all yet, the answer in the other question seems to be spot on about how to approach it with your boss. Why do you think it's not applicable?

Comment: @yymoteusz while that question maybe a good way to approach my boss, I have twice and then nothing happens. If you understand the context of my situation you would see I am asking more about the next more on my part after it seems I am being lied to by my current boss. If I should go higher up or just start looking for a new job.

Comment: OK, so you’re asking if going around your boss to get a raise is possible/a good idea?

Comment: In case it's not clear, you have 4 close votes because you've worded this as, "Should I do A or B?", which is off topic, instead of as, "Is A a good idea?".

Comment: .... because "only" two years instead of 2 1/2 is so much better?  Don't bother negotiating or asking. Go find a better offer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This company I am working for also has my same position at 30% more in
> salary then me as well as a starting base I seen on the postings, as
> they continue to hire new people and keep expanding the team.
>
> I am becoming annoyed and starting to feel as I am being lied to about
> every getting a raise, along with the fact I am not being paid
> correctly as well.

Just because someone shares a job title that doesn't mean you are going to be on equal pay, or that you deliver the same thing, have the same skillset or experience or negotiating skills. Getting angry about other people salaries will do you nothing good - you need to focus on your own instead. Additionally what's posted on job adds is not always what the company in the end will pay a new hire.

So stop worrying about other people's income and this should help a bit with the annoyed feeling about not getting "correctly paid".

Ask yourself whether you are adequately paid, and the only real way to determine it is to go out there and try to find a new job, see what sort of offers will come your way. Until you do that you are worth about as much as you are paid now, barring some extreme cases.

> Should I talk to the director of the team going over my manager to get
> answers ?( This worries me as I feel this can make my life difficult,
> by my manager if I do this).

Unless you have some outstanding personal relation with your bosses boss, I would never do that. You are going behind your bosses back and over his head at the very same time, and unless that person will 100% agree with your views this will backfire. How bad will that be is unknown until it happens, but you definitely are better off without that heat.

> What are some options I should move forward with?
>
> Should I just forget it and just look for a new job

Yes, very much so.

When a company grossly underpays you (as you portray it to be the case) then generally speaking the only way to get adequate pay is to change employers. You can try to leverage a new offer into a raise here, but that's not exactly a good outcome for you as this means that they could afford it, and knew that you are worth it, and you asked for it, and yet they didn't do anything about it until you threatened to quit for a greener pasture.

So go, apply for some jobs, keep it on the down low and hopefully you will find one with adequate pay. If not, then maybe you should take a moment and reevaluate your self-evaluation.

> (I really don't want to as the culture is nice).

In that case you will have to live with the fact that they've been underpaying you, and will continue doing so. Anything that gets you out of this rot, besides politely, and not too often, asking your boss, is going to rock the boat and risk your stay with the company. You have to decide for yourself what's more important to you, staying with company which culture you enjoy, or the higher pay and an unknown culture somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately OP does know the salaries of new hires into the team so how can one possibly forget that knowledge to live in a happy bubble? Also OP knows that they are inadequately paid, they've already asked themselves that question hence their post on here.

Comment: @OldNick I'll tell you a secret, every single person in the universe thinks that they are underpaid, in the end who wouldn't want to be paid more than they are? But just because you think so doesn't mean that you are, and the only thing to validate your market worth is to either get a raise, or a job offer for what you think your worth it. If you didn't do that, stop worrying about other people's income. Sure, you can't "unsee it" but so what? I know a lot of stuff which I decide not to worry about it.

Comment: Paul, is there any reason for your condescending comment? OPs question states that a promised pay review did not materialise, actually has not had a pay rise since starting there, the company advertise the same job for a 30% higher salary and also median salaries for similar positions are higher, Did you not read that before you wrote your reply?

Comment: @OldNick I did and I covered that in the answer that positions, adverts and so on mean nothing, as pay varies from person to person. Just going around and looking for higher paying jobs with similar title is how you get in "i am unhappy" spiral. And this is not being condescending at all, just reality of the job market that unless someone is actually offering to pay you more then you are worth what you are being paid now.

Comment: If OP has been working for two and a half years without a raise, I don't think one has to do market research to know whether one is worth more to the company as an employee after 2.5 years of experience vs. being a new hire. I would agree with "apply for jobs and field offers," but strictly with the idea of leaving.  If it takes an offer to leverage a raise, then the employees' time is limited anyway, and forcing a counter-offer from the current employee fixes none of the issues that created the problem in the first place.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet why do you think that a new hire cannot do a better job than someone with 2.5 year experience? They certainly can, and it all depends from person to person, what have they done with their time - work and non work wise. And as I've said in the answer, move on, counter offer to get a raise is sign to get out.

Comment: What are you talking about?  I never said that.  "It all depends on person to person" - I'm talking about THIS person now, vs THIS person 2.5 years ago.  No raises. I'm not talking about what anyone else earns.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I know plenty of people who sat on a job for 2.5 years and have learned almost nothing, happens all the time. Do you have some insider information on OP to say he isn't one of them?

Comment: The fact that he is still employed.  If he learned nothing and was no better than a new hire, do you really think the boss would be saying "let's see after this project" or, after the project, would make positive indications. You think the employee would have to ask, if their reviews came back as "LEARNED NOTHING IN 2.5 years"? Hey, but maybe you've worked with lousy workers and lousy companies, exclusively and don't realize that's not normal. You're being pedantic and intentionally obtuse. How can we "prove" anything anyone says on this site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113006/discussion-between-tymoteusz-paul-and-poloholeset).

Answer (score 4):

It's not uncommon for an employer to find an excuse to get an extra 3-6 months of work out of you before giving you a promotion you already earned. Plus however long it took you to decide to ask.

Some would say that you should never worry about how much other employees make. I disagree. There will be differences in pay due to the negotiating skills of the new hire & how badly the company wants them but the salary number a company posts in a job ad has nothing to do with negotiating and it's setting the minimum for your specific job.  If the boss is telling you he can't give you a raise to the level of a new hire who will be doing what you've already been doing at the company for 2+ years there's a problem.

> What are some options I should move forward with?

> Should I talk to the director of the team going over my manager to get answers ?( This worries me as I feel this can make my life difficult, by my manager if I do this).

The fact you seriously are considering going over your boss's head means that you have a bad boss. 75% chance it's all his fault. 25% chance it's partly yours & partly his... according to [There's no such thing as going over your boss's head, originleadership.com](https://originleadership.com/there-is-no-such-thing-as-going-over-your-bosss-head/)

You should never go over your manager's head (unless it's about serious misconduct/illegality). Your manager's boss isn't going to override him. More likely he would let your boss fire you and *then* think about dealing with your boss.

I tried it once at a small company with a toxic manager. I went to the owner & discussed things. The owner agreed with me and even went beyond anything I said and said my manager was an idiot... but he did not lift a finger to help me. Nothing changed. I was too valuable for them to fire me but I had to quit.

> Should I just forget it and just look for a new job(I really don't want to as the culture is nice).

The culture isn't nice if they are offering new hires a minimum that is higher than what you're making for doing the exact same job. They know that will impact morale & they don't care.

"Equitable pay refers to internal consistency of salary amongst employees within an organization. Internally equitable salary structure will help ensure employees receive proportionally fair treatment in terms of pay, anchored on clearly-defined expectations, as regularly communicated by the employer... Statistics from Aptitude Research Partners associate organizations with a formal pay equity process to 19% more likely to exceed industry-average levels of productivity... 54% more likely to beat industry-average turnover benchmarks." From [salary.com](https://www.salary.com/blog/equitable-pay-the-modern-workforce-demands-it/#:%7E:text=Equitable%20pay%20refers%20to%20internal,regularly%20communicated%20by%20the%20employer)

> Should I just forget it and just look for a new job(I really don't want to as the culture is nice).

If I'm in your shoes I would 1. Go for promotion over the next 6 months. That higher job title will help (not guarantee) you making more money. Then start looking for a new job after promotion.  If you go to a new job without the promotion it might be another 2-3 years before you get promoted... depending on the employer.

Comment: `but the salary number a company posts in a job ad has nothing to do with negotiating and it's setting the minimum for your specific job.` I don't see that stated anywhere in OPs post, where did you get it from? For all we know what's posted vs what's actually offered may be very different, and OP nowhere said that it's some mandated minimum.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul When a company posts a specific salary number that number is the minimum for someone who meets all of the stated requirements. OP said: "This company I am working for also has my same position at 30% more in salary then me as well as a starting base I seen on the postings."    Of course the pay a hire gets may be HIGHER than what was in the ad but it won't be lower (unless the new higher is basically a retarded negotiator). Hence my "minimum" comment.

Comment: This may be cultural then, but that certainly does not work like minimum in many places I've seen. Far from it being a guarantee really, and varies wildly between candidates, and yep, often enough to the point where it feels like bait and switch (and probably is).

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Okay, fair enough. In the US, when an employer offers a lower number than was in the job ad, the applicant just walks away. It's an insult and a sign that they will do horrible things to you on the job anyhow so there's no point going for the lower offer. I menetioned [Salary is most important part of job ad](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/talent-acquisition/pages/salary-most-important-part-job-ad.aspx) in the other comment before I edited. Not sure if you saw that so I re-added it here.

Comment: Yep, i saw it and I agree fully about the importance of salary! In Europe the bait-and-switch model is substantially a lot more common, and while some people indeed walk, some will take the job because that's still their best offer. Which is why I do not take advertised salary as word of gospel, as even in honest companies that want to offer the salary, it may then be reduced for probation period etc. So not something to hang up on too much.

Answer (score 4):

For literally decades now, the running joke in IT, at least, has been that if you want a raise, you should find another job.

Twice, I have seen people go through this.  My present employer pulled this on a former coworker.  They refused to meet his requirements, then when he quit, they ended up advertising his role, with fewer duties, for more money than he had asked for.

He had the last laugh by coming back as a consultant and they were paying him nearly double that when the systems collapsed.  Nearly an identical situation happened with a friend of mine where the company felt his salary was too high, and they let him go.  The systems degraded to where they were more in a month than they were paying him for three years.

When they asked him to come back, he told them his consulting rate, and they couldn't get approval for anything that high.

Your situation is far from  unique.

### **WHAT I WOULD SUGGEST**

Go on some interviews until you get an offer.  The next day, go to your manager, and ask for the money you want.  **DO NOT MENTION THAT YOU HAVE AN OFFER**

If management agrees, take the money from your company and stay in your position.  If they don't agree to the salary bump, accept the offer, and move on.  **ACCEPT NO COUNTER OFFERS.**  If the only reason they want to pay you more is that you've got another offer, they're not worth your time.

Comment: **ACCEPT NO COUNTER OFFERS** - can't emphasize that enough.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Good suggesstion.

Answer (score 2):

> I explained that since my start I have not received a raise ever since I started working here 2 half years ago, and his reply was that my first 6 months of employment cannot be counted, since it's probationary period of employment.(that really doesn't make sense since I was working during this time). So he said it's only been two years not two and half

I will focus on this. For me the probation period is tied with "probation pay". So let's say the company salaries for position vary from X to Y. During probation period (IMHO 6 months is VERY long) you are paid lowest amount as the company is evaluating your "real" worth. Your salary might change or it might not.

BUT after two years of which we know for sure you ended some goals the rise should be in order. OR proper communication: When you joined company we estimated you as B, after 6 months in company your value was C and your input was Z. After two years you are D and you're doing F.

So the first 6 months count. Paying you the same amount as when you joined the company means that your knowledge, abilites and input is THE SAME as on day 1. Do you feel that way?
What I'm seeing is dodging the talk and trying to make you stay as long as it's possible. Because your boss, or your boss boss, or the company as a whole want to underpay you. And as long as you're happy with it (so don't change jobs) they will continue to do it. Especially now when they have "death in the family" excuse to not give raises (covid-19).

Answer (score 1):

If they are advertising the same job 30% higher but not forthcoming with a rise then you should think about moving on. Unfortunately many companies take advantage of inertia - you like the culture there, it's comfortable so you put up with being paid 2/3rds of your worth.

2 years experience counts for a lot on the job market. Your boss has shown he is more interested in stringing you along and realistically probably won't agree to a 30%+ pay rise anyway.

This is the unfortunate reality of the jobs market, especially in tech.

Comment: Yes, 2 years is no longer a noob, and anyone who can hold down a job for that long has proven they are not a screwball.  Good answer.